# Undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, squeel

I have been working on a program called Ctrlpanlel for some time now and I have it up on Heroku and it is working... mostly with only a few exceptions. For background it used to run on Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.1 and I have upgraded it to Ruby 2.7.2 and Rails 6.1.3.2

One of the functions this app does is weekly expense reports and I am having a problem with some of the query logic because it was originally written using a gem called squeel. I am very new to Rails and Activerecord although I am learning I am trying to un-squeel the code in a few places.  I believe I have the first couple of queries fixed (I think at least) and it goes past the first couple of part where I was running into an error, I can run the task by running rails weekly_expense_reports and it goes to the letter opener with no issues and shows the people and the number of charges they each have but then it also says the following error for each one of them:

> ERROR processing Smith John because: undefined method `order' for #ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000001067ee08

I changed the employees name to John Smith just to be clear. :)

It does this for each person so I know either the first query I thought I fixed properly I did NOT, or there is another issue in the controller in the section that has the .order lines in it which is what it is referring to.  I have learned that sometimes in Rails when it points to a bad method sometimes it is the data supplying the method that is the issue and not necessarily the method itself.  In this case I am not sure which one it is.

The first line I changed is:

```rb
@users = User.where.not(:expense_reports_to_user_id => nil)
```

The second line I changed is:

```rb
charge_count = Charge.between_times( start_date, end_date, field: :post_date ).
                       where(:cardholder_name => user.cardholder_name).count
```

Here is the TASK in scheduler.rake

```
task :weekly_expense_reports => :environment do
  
  if Time.zone.now.wday == 2
    log = []
#    Squeel logic I had to de-squeel v0.0040 on 5/10/2021 Scott Milella   
#    @users = User.where{ expense_reports_to_user_id.not_eq nil }

     @users = User.where.not(:expense_reports_to_user_id => nil)    # <- First Line I changed

    message = "Evaluating #{@users.count} users"
    puts message
    log << message

    start_date = Time.zone.today - 7.days
    end_date   = Time.zone.today - 1.days

    if Charge.between_times( start_date, end_date, field: :post_date ).any?
      date_ranges = []

      if start_date.month == end_date.month
        date_ranges << { start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date }
      else
        date_ranges << { start_date: start_date, end_date: start_date.end_of_month }
        date_ranges << { start_date: end_date.beginning_of_month, end_date: end_date }
      end

      message = "Found charges in date ranges: #{date_ranges.join(" to ")}"
      puts message
      log << message

      @users.each do |user|
        puts "Checking #{user.name} for charges..."

#  Below here is the next query I changed...
#        More squeel code yet again, v0.0040 on 5/10/2021 Scott Milella
#       charge_count = Charge.between_times( start_date, end_date, field: :post_date ).
#                       where{ cardholder_name.eq my{ user.cardholder_name } }.count

        charge_count = Charge.between_times( start_date, end_date, field: :post_date ).
                       where(:cardholder_name => user.cardholder_name).count


        if charge_count > 0
          message = "Found #{charge_count} charges for #{user.name}"
          puts message
          log << message

          begin
            ExpenseMailer.weekly_report(user, date_ranges).deliver_now!
            sleep 1

            message = "Successfully emailed charges for #{user.name}"
            puts message
            log << message
          rescue Exception => error
            message = "ERROR processing #{user.name} because: #{error}"
            puts message
            log << message
          end
        end
      end

      # finished processing emails, send report
      log << "Finished Processing Expense Reports"
      ActionMailer::Base.mail(
        from: "tech@des.direct",
        to: "terrym@des.direct",
        subject: "Expense Report Summary",
        body: log.join("\n\n").html_safe
      ).deliver_now
    else
      # no charges found, send notification
      emails = ["terrym@des.direct", "laurah@des.direct"]
      puts "No charges were found, skipping expense report."
      ActionMailer::Base.mail(
        from: "tech@des.direct",
        to: emails,
        subject: "[Expense Reports] No Charges Found, Cannot Process",
        body: "Error, no charges were uploaded for the period of #{start_date} to #{end_date}, please reprocess manually."
      ).deliver_now
    end
    log = nil
  end
end
```

Here is the model just in case:

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :card_last_four, :cardholder_name, :cardholder_last_name, :cardholder_origin,
    :post_date, :merchant_name, :amount, :trans_type, :gl_code, :mcc_code,
    :mcc_description, :gas_region, :transaction_date

  before_save :add_cardholder_last_name

  def add_cardholder_last_name
    if cardholder_name
      self.cardholder_last_name = cardholder_name.split(" ").last
    end
  end

  def self.allowed_user_ids
    administration_user_ids
  end

  def self.administration_user_ids
    [ 8,
      9,
      36,
      50,
      128 # 
    ] # this includes  (not in order)
  end

  def update_gl_code
    self.gl_code = Charge.mcc_to_gl_table[mcc_code.to_i]
    self.save
  end

  def self.mcc_to_gl_table
    {
    0    => 740,
    }
  end

  def self.cardholder_name_select
    Charge.pluck(:cardholder_name).
    uniq.
    delete_if{ |x| x.in?( Charge.cardholder_reject_list ) }.
    reject(&:blank?).
    sort_by{ |k| k.split(" ").last }
  end

  def self.cardholder_reject_list
    [
      "JOHN DOE",
      "JOHN DOE",
      "JOHN DOE",
      "JOHN DOE",
      
    ]
  end

  def self.cardholder_name_to_details
    {
    "ACCOUNTS PAYABLE"          => { branch: "redding",     region: "TRAVEL" },
  
    }
  end

  def self.import_csv_text(csv_text)
    require 'csv'

    csv = CSV.parse( csv_text, headers: true )

    csv.each do |raw|
      row = raw.to_hash

      merchant_name      = row["Merchant Name"].strip

      if merchant_name == "PAYMENT - THANK YOU"
        card_last_four     = 0
        cardholder_name    = "Payment"
      else
        if row["Originating Account Number"].present?
          card_last_four     = row["Originating Account Number"][-4, 4]
          cardholder_name    = row["Cardholder Name"].strip
        else
          cardholder_name    = "ACCOUNTS PAYABLE"
          card_last_four     = 1234
        end
      end

      transaction_date   = Chronic.parse( row["Tran Date"] ).to_date
      post_date          = Chronic.parse( row["Post Date"] ).to_date
      amount             = row["Amount"].remove('$')
      trans_type         = row["Tran Type"].strip
      mcc_code           = row["MCC Code"].to_i
      mcc_description    = row["MCC Description"].strip
      reference_number   = row["Reference Number"].strip

      gl_code            = Charge.mcc_to_gl_table[ mcc_code ]

      cardholder_details = Charge.cardholder_name_to_details[ cardholder_name ]

      if cardholder_details
        cardholder_origin  = cardholder_details[:branch]
        gas_region         = cardholder_details[:region]
      end

      @charge = Charge.where(reference_number: reference_number, amount: amount).first_or_create

      @charge.card_last_four    = card_last_four
      @charge.transaction_date  = transaction_date
      @charge.post_date         = post_date
      @charge.merchant_name     = merchant_name
      @charge.cardholder_name   = cardholder_name
      @charge.trans_type        = trans_type
      @charge.mcc_code          = mcc_code        unless @charge.mcc_code.present?
      @charge.mcc_description   = mcc_description unless @charge.mcc_description.present?
      @charge.gl_code           = gl_code         unless @charge.gl_code.present?
      @charge.cardholder_origin = cardholder_origin unless @charge.cardholder_origin.present?
      @charge.gas_region        = gas_region      unless @charge.gas_region.present?

      @charge.save

    end
  end
end
```

Here is the complete error from the rails panel with the employee names changed:

```
From:
tech@email.domain
Subject:
Expense Report Summary
Date:
May 11, 2021 03:41:12 PM Pacific Daylight Time
To:
Tech@email.domain
Evaluating 38 users

Found charges in date ranges: {:start_date=>Tue, 04 May 2021, :end_date=>Mon, 10 May 2021}

Found 10 charges for John Doe

ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000cc282e0>

Found 3 charges for John Doe

ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0000000009970410>


Found 1 charges for John Doe

ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000000106fc830>

Finished Processing Expense Reports
```

I appreciate any advice, recommendations, solutions anyone has to offer!

Thank You,

Scott

Here is a copy strait from the rails panel, this is the only way I know of to manually trigger this script.  Normally it would be called from Heroku Scheduler.

```
scottm@RED-IT-LAP-0001 MINGW64 /d/rails/ctrlpanel (master)
$ rake weekly_expense_reports
Evaluating 38 users
Found charges in date ranges: {:start_date=>Wed, 05 May 2021, :end_date=>Tue, 11 May 2021}
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 8 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000f06fdb0>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 2 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000f3bec78>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 5 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000dfc0a50>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 1 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000f5e1fa0>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 1 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe  because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000f653420>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 1 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000dbfbe38>
Found 5 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000000f70ac38>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 5 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0000000010614328>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 1 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000000106cc810>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 3 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000001072c6c0>
Checking John Doe for charges...
Found 1 charges for John Doe
ERROR processing John Doe because: undefined method `order' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x000000001078d2e0>

scottm@RED-IT-LAP-0001 MINGW64 /d/rails/ctrlpanel (master)
$
```

As you can see above it pretty much gives me the very same information as what was on the email which is not very helpful.  Sorry that I provided too much code, I thought I only provided the necessary code around the issue and people usually ask me for more.

The lines it is referencing as having the problem are in the charges_controller.rb but I am concerned that the queries I modified (and possibly incorrectly) might be the reason it is saying the method is undefined, because the controller logic looks ok to me?  But then again I am very new and still struggling to understand the Rails logic.
The method from the control is below::

```
def index
    if current_user.id.in?( Charge.administration_user_ids ) || current_user.cardholder_name.present?
      params[:q] = {} if params[:q].blank?
      params[:q][:post_date_gteq] = Date.today.beginning_of_month - 1.month if params[:q][:post_date_gteq].blank?

      # pre-set the cardholder name if they've been assigned
      # unless they're an administrator
      if current_user.cardholder_name.present? && !current_user.id.in?( Charge.administration_user_ids )
        params[:q]["cardholder_name_eq"] = current_user.cardholder_name
      end

      @q = Charge.ransack(params[:q])

      # done too quickly, seriously needs rework
      if params[:q][:cardholder_name_eq].present?
        if current_user.id.in?( Charge.administration_user_ids )
          @charges = @q.result.order(:gl_code, :post_date).group_by(&:gl_code)
        else
          @charges = @q.result.order(:cardholder_name, :post_date)  
        end
      else
        @charges = @q.result.order(:cardholder_name, :post_date)
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Nope."
    end
  end
```

To be clear I renamed all of the employee names to John Doe.  :)

If there is anything else you need please let me know and thank you again!
Scott

I removed the log file since it was made clear that it was pretty much the same information in a different way.

Here is the file in app/mailers/expense_mailer.rb

```
class ExpenseMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def weekly_report(user, date_ranges)
    require 'prawn'

    date_ranges.each do | range |
      start_date = range[ :start_date ]
      end_date   = range[ :end_date ]

      @charges = Charge.between_times( start_date, end_date, field: :post_date ).
                        where{cardholder_name.eq my { user.cardholder_name } }.
                        order("post_date asc")

      if @charges.any?
        prawn_output  = ExpenseReport.new(user.cardholder_name, start_date, end_date, @charges).render
        prawn_object  = CombinePDF.parse(prawn_output, page_layout: :landscape)
        combined_file = CombinePDF.new

        template_path  = 'app/assets/pdfs/DES_Expense_Report_W4.pdf'
        template_page  = CombinePDF.load( template_path, page_layout: :landscape ).pages[0] ; true

        prawn_object.pages.each do |page|
          template_page  = CombinePDF.load( template_path, page_layout: :landscape ).pages[0] ; true
          template_page[:Annots].each { |a|
            a[:referenced_object][:T] = 'Combine' + SecureRandom.hex(7) + 'PDF'
          }

          combined_file << template_page
        end

        prawn_object.pages.each_with_index do |page, i|
          combined_file.pages[i] << prawn_object.pages[i]
        end

        page_total = combined_file.pages.count
        combined_file.pages.each_with_index do |page, i|
          page.textbox( "Page #{i + 1}/#{page_total}", x: 680, y: -520, max_font_size: 10 )
        end

        attachments["#{user.cardholder_name} [ #{start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")} - #{end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")} ].pdf"] = combined_file.to_pdf
      end
    end

    to_with_name   = %("#{user.expense_report_manager.name}" <#{user.expense_report_manager.email}>)
    # to_with_name   = %("John" <johnd@mail.domain>)
    from_with_name = %("CtrlPanel" <tech@mail.domain>)

    mail to: to_with_name, bcc: 'tech@mail.domain 
from: from_with_name, subject: "Expense Report for #{user.name} [ #{date_ranges.first[:start_date].strftime("%m/%d/%Y")} - #{date_ranges.last[:end_date].strftime("%m/%d/%Y")} ]"
  end
end
```

Thank You,
Scott

Comment: Hey there, the error raised was probably raised inside ExpenseMailer.weekly_report(user, date_ranges). Can you add some code to this method?

Comment: Phew to much unnecessary code. Can you isolate the line where the error happens and remove everything thats not related to that? Also since no error logs are provided you should try to be able to trigger the error manually instead of just checking the mail. This way you can isolate where it happens and it is far easier to debug.

Comment: Thank You @DennyMueller,  I added the additional information above.  I am sorry that I included too much, I thought people would want to see everything related, Towards the end of my initial question you will find the update and the controller logic it is referring to.  I am also concerned though that the queries I modified may be the reason it is saying the method is undefined as I can find .order in the rails documentation and it looked correct to me?  Of course I am new and still struggling to understand active record.

Comment: I also had to remove some of the duplicates of the log file as I hit some kind of a limit with respect to the body of the question?

Comment: This is just the the same information in different form. Additionally I can't see how the controller has anything to do with it. Since the rake task is not using it at all. My guess is since the error comes definitely from `rescue Exception => error` catch it has to happen in the the `begin` block. Throw out all the logs and the controller code and controller action. Lets get that cleaned up. Do you use `pry`?

Comment: and please provide code for `ExpenseMailer.weekly_report(user, date_ranges).deliver_now!`

Comment: Ok controller logic removed and I also remove the log entries as you said it was the same info in a different way.   I didn't realize that the tasks do not use the controller I thought it was still integrated somehow.  So when I run rails weekly_expense_reports to execute the task that is similar to running ruby file_name.rb?   I have pry and byebug in the gemfile but I don't know how to use them, I tried byebug but it seems to ignore it when I place it anyplace, Windows error maybe I read, unconfirmed.  I will read the instructions on how to use Pry and see if I can understand it.  TY Again!!

Comment: I think I found the issue!

Comment: I had to change: where{cardholder_name.eq my { user.cardholder_name } }.
                        order("post_date asc")
to:  where(:cardholder_name => user.cardholder_name).
                        order("post_date asc")

Comment: I didn't realize the ExpenseMailer.weekly_report was calling another file which is why I was looking at the wrong logic with regards to .orrder. I thought it was going to the chargest_controller.rb  You asked me for the other file, that clued me in that another file existed. I posted it on my question as you asked and noticed there was an order in it, looked at it and noticed it used Squeel code I think at least.. Once I made that change it stated working properly.  .eq is squeel logic I assume or a change in the way newer rails uses the query perhaps? This app originally had squeel in it.

Comment: Holy guacamole those methods are WAAAAY too long. Split this into methods that do ONE job like sending an email or creating a PDF file and you'll have a much easier time actually isolating the problem and debugging in general.

Comment: Thank You @max  .  This APP needs a lot of refactoring, appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be in the Expense_Mailer.rb file.
It had logic from an old gem called squeel.

This line had the bad logic in it:

```
where{cardholder_name.eq my { user.cardholder_name } }.order("post_date asc")
```

Changed it to:

```
where(:cardholder_name => user.cardholder_name).order("post_date asc")
```

Then it started working properly.
Thank You again @Denny Mueller if you had not informed me that it was calling out to another file I wouldn't have found that other logic.  Still trying to fully understand how rails is all tied together.

Comment: Just FYI: be consistent on how to use key:value syntax in hashes. Either use the old hash-rocket `:key => value` or the JSON syntax `key: value`. Like old-style `where(:cardholder_name => user.cardholder_name)`, new-style `where(cardholder_name: user.cardholder_name)`

Comment: Thank You @DennyMueller  I didn't know I had an option?  I am still trying to learn Ruby/Rails & struggling to learn everything.  I have been reading docs on Rails at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/, watching tutorials etc. but still am struggling.  My background is PC Hardware but just in the last 2 years decided to start learning Soft. Dev. Stated with Java, got to an intermediate level there. Can write web aps with Spring. The company I worked for lost their Rails Dev so I took it on; that was a month and a half ago or so.  Open to any recommendations anyone has to increase skills TY Again!